# Probability about a geometric distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

Bill, Mary and Tom have coins with respective probabilities $p_1,p_2,p_3$ of turning up heads. They toss their coins independently at the same times.

What is the probability that neither Bill nor Tom get a head before Mary?

---

I tried to write it down as a geometric distribution but the equation became extremely long. I believe there must be an easier way to look at this problem.

Comment: This is why I hate this question. It's like they teach you something and when you try to use it, you get rekt. I get they're trying to teach you to think outside of the box, but come on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each group of simultaneous tosses has three possible outcomes. If Mary obtains "head", the game is over with positive outcome. If Bill and/or Tom obtains "head" and Mary doesn't, the game is over with negative outcome. If no-one obtains "head", the game continues with the same probabilities as before. Thus, the probability of a positive outcome is the sum of three contributions:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
p&=&p_2\cdot1+(1-(1-p_1)(1-p_3))(1-p_2)\cdot0+(1-p_1)(1-p_2)(1-p_3)\cdot p\\
&=&p_2\cdot1+(1-p_1)(1-p_2)(1-p_3)\cdot p\;.
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Solving for $p$ yields

$$p=\frac{p_2}{1-(1-p_1)(1-p_2)(1-p_3)}\;.$$

Comment: Could you explain how you obtained the individual probabilities? In particular, $P($Bill and/or Tom obtains "head" and Mary doesn't$) = (1−(1−p_1)(1−p_3))(1−p_2) \cdot 0$ and $P($no-one obtains "head"$) = (1−p_1)(1−p_2)(1−p_3) \cdot p$